# Prove that any smooth submanifold $H\le G$ of a Lie group is closed

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Let $G\subset{\rm GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ be a matrix Lie group, with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g\equiv T_{I}G$. Let $H\le G$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $\mathfrak h$ be its Lie algebra. Denote with $\mathfrak h^\perp$ the orthogonal complement of $\mathfrak h$ with respect to some inner product. I want to prove that, if $H$ is a *smooth submanifold* of $G$, then $H$ must be closed.

A way to prove this is given in [these pdf notes](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/diffgeo.pdf) (page 62, theorem 2.5.26). The idea of the proof, as far as I understand it, is as follows:

1. Take a converging sequence $(h_i)_i\subset H$ with $h_i\to g\in G$. We want to prove that $g\in H$. Observe that $h_i^{-1}g\to I$, where $I\in G$ is the identity in $G$.
2. Observe that there is a neighbourhood of $I\in G$ all the elements of which can be *uniquely represented* as $h e^\xi$ for some $h\in H$ and $\xi\in\mathfrak h^\perp$. This implies that for all $i$ large enough, there are unique $h_i'\in H$ and $\xi_i\in\mathfrak h^\perp$ (taken in suitable neighbourhoods of $I\in H$ and $0\in\mathfrak h^\perp$, respectively) such that $g=h_i h_i' e^{\xi_i}$.
3. Observe that any $\xi,\xi'\in\mathfrak h^\perp$ with small enough norm and such that $e^\xi e^{-\xi'}\in H$ must be equal: $\xi=\xi'$.
4. Because $\xi_i\to 0$, conclude that for large enough $i$ we must have $\xi_i=0$, and thus $g=h_i h_i'\in H$.

What I'm trying to understand better is the role of $\mathfrak h^\perp$ in this reasoning. Does it have to do with $\xi\in\mathfrak h^\perp$ representing a "direction on $G$ orthogonal to those spanning $H$"? What is an intuitive argument that might lead one to guess that this way of decomposing elements close to the identity $I\in G$ is suitable to prove this result?

Comment: The "orthogonality" wrt a scalar product is irrelevant, you can take any algebraic complement of $\mathfrak h$. But taking an orthogonal complement helps you understand the role of the $\mathfrak h^\perp$, which is to take care of the directions going away from $H$.